# ENTER in fpdf when $_POST function.. ln ()?

Tags: php, web, fpdf, fpdi

Is there any code I can put in the input post text so that when appearing on fpdf it gives an enter space (to the next line) ..???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use FPDF::Multicell() or FPDF::Write() and it should be done automatically.

Comment: hey! thnx for responding... say i put that in my <input text... so that it delivers in fpdf...it just displays the text but no enter..

Comment: No. You need to use these functions to write text to PDF.